# Are subcaption, cleveref and hyperref compatible?

Tags: hyperref, subcaption, cleveref

I tried with this MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{caption,subcaption}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

See \cref{subfig1}, \ref{subfig1}

\begin{figure}
 \subcaptionbox{Subfigure\label{subfig1}}
  {A FIGURE}
\caption{Figure}
\label{fig1}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Without `hyperref`, all is nice, with `hyperref` I get ?? for the `\cref` instance. I tried installing the latest versions of all three packages, nothing changed apparently.

Comment: You do know that you have to load `cleveref` _after_ `hyperref`, right?

Comment: @JosephWright I didn't know, now I do. As in the question kindly linked by @egreg, I assumed that `hyperref` had to be loaded last.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to load `cleveref` after `hyperref`. Then everything works.

> See fig. 1a, 1a

It is kind of mentioned in the manual:

> If you are using both varioref and hyperref, make sure you are loading
>   them in the correct order, otherwise cross-references will reference completely
>   the wrong thing without any warning in the LATEX output or log! The packages
>   must be loaded in the following order: varioref, hyperref, cleveref.